# Set command with two possibilities for setting the property value

Tags: matlab, properties, set

For some hobjects in matlab, the `set(hobject, 'enable', 'inactive')` command will work fine. 
 for others, like toolbar buttons, there's only `set(hobject, 'enable', 'off')`.

Is I have a set of `listObjects`, 
is there something like `set(listObjects, 'enable', ['inactive'|'off'])` in which I set the property to 'inactive' if it's valid, and 'off' if it's not a valid property?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two values that you need to check, you can use a `try/catch` block.

```
try
    set(hobject,'enable','inactive');
catch exception
    if strcmp(exception.identifier,'MATLAB:hg:propswch:FindObjFailed')
        set(hobject,'enable','off');
    else
        throw(exception)
    end
end
```

This way it checks the first time you try to set the value, if it is acceptable. If not, it tries the next alternative. If the error is due to something else (for e.g., you entered an invalid property name), it throws the error to the screen.

BTW, the error identifier: `MATLAB:hg:propswch:FindObjFailed` was what I got on my machine when I tried to set a value that the property wouldn't accept. Although I suspect it should be the same, you might want to see what you get on your machine and use that in the `strcmp` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the 'type' of objects by reading their `'enable'` property first.

```
enableStatus = get(listOfObjects,'enable');

%# identify who is active and who is on
activeObjects = listOfObjects(strcmp(enableStatus,'active'));
onObjects = listOfObjects(strcmp(enableStatus,'on'));

%# set proper status
set(activeObjects,'enable','inactive')
set(onObjects,'enable','off')
```